# How to count consecutive string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Here is what I have done:

```
seq = [0,1,1,1,0]
num = 0
for i in seq:
    if seq[i] == seq[i+1]:
        num = num+1
    else:
        continue
print(num)
```

I am expected to come up with the number of occurence of '11' in the sequence, i.e. '11' and '11' and the answer is saying 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Comment: You are iterating the list, `seq`, not the positions. You should use `for i, n in enumerate(seq):` where `i` is the index e.g. `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` and `n` is the number e.g. `0, 1, 1, 1, 0`

Comment: This is useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use `seq[i+1]`, you must stop one before the end of the sequence. In addition, you should use enumerate to access the index in the sequence as well as the value:

```
seq = [0,1,1,1,0]
nums = 0
for i, x in enumerate(seq[:-1]):
    if x == seq[i+1]:
        nums += 1
print(nums)
```

Comment: Thanks . well appreciated